# Linked list addBegnining with parameterized list

Tags: java, linked-list

I've wrote a method in my implementation of my interface that takes a linked list in parameter and has to return an arraylist of all the items that exists already and weren't added to the class list.

Here's the signature:

`public List<T> addBegining(ListeOfEmployees<T> list);`

My methode add's the elements in the linked list of the class in inverse.

Lets say the parameter list:

```
Employee1
Employee2
Employee3
Employee4
Employee5
```

Actual list in the class:

```
Employee2
Employee4
Employee5
```

It's suppose to return an ArrayList in the same order of the parameter list:

```
1-Employee2
2-Employee4
3-Employee5
```

But it returns an ArrayList like this:

```
1-Employee5
2-Employee4
3-Employee2
```

I used a `while()` to cycle thru my parametered list but it goes from begining to end.

I don't know how I can cycle thrue the parameterized list but from the end to the beginning.
I cannot use a pointer at the end of the list for this method.

I'm out of solutions here.

Here's what i've done so far:

```
public List<T> addBegining(ListeOfEmployees<T> list) {
    List<T> res = null;
    T return;

    Iterator<T> it = list.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext() && list != null) {
        return = it.next();
        if (this.hasElement(return)) {
            if (res == null) {
                res = new ArrayList<T>();
            }
            res.add(retour);
        } else {
            this.addBegining(retour);
            nbElm++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please show some attempts as oppose to directly asking for the solution.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here's what i've worked so far.

My solution doesnt enter the list the same way the linked list was passed has a parameter

Comment: The code obviously doesn't compile.

Comment: what is `T return;` ? have you compiled your code yet?

Comment: T return is a generic type of variable since i'm implementing a class.